# Rank of Truncations of Block Binomial Coefficient Matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to compute the ranks of sub-matrices of matrices of a block Pascal type: 
$$
M^{(n, m)} = \begin{bmatrix}
    L_{n} & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & 0 \\
    ZL_{n-1} & L_{n-1} & 0 & \ldots & 0  \\
   Z^2L_{n-2} & ZL_{n-2} & L_{n-2} & \ldots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   Z^mL_{n-m} & Z^{m-1}L_{n-m} & Z^{m-2}L_{n-m} & \ldots & L_{n-m}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $L_n$ is the $n$ x $n$ lower triangular Pascal matrix with coefficients
 $$(L_n)_{jk} = \binom{j}{k}$$ and $Z^iL_n$ a right shifted lower triangular Pascal matrix with coefficients
$$(Z^iL_n)_{jk} = \begin{cases}\binom{j-i}{k}, \quad &j-i \geq 0\\ 0, \quad &j-i < 0\end{cases}.$$
For example 
$$A=M^{(2,2)} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|cc|c}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 &  0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
   1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].$$

I am considering truncations of these matrices, for example

$$A_{[1,2:5],[0:4]} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1  \\
\hline
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{array}\right],$$ which has rank 4.

Might there be a method for computing the rank depending only on $n,m$ and the selection of rows and columns? I would also be interested in a non-trivial upper bound based on the selection of the rows and columns.

I am aware of the work done for submatrices of the upper triangular Pascal matrix in:

> Invertibility of Submatrices of Pascal's Matrix and Birkhoff Interpolation (arXiv:[1303.6159](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6159))
>
> Rank of Submatrices of the Pascal Matrix (arXiv:[1702.03194](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03194))

The author found an algorithm for computing the rank of sub-matrices of the Pascal matrix based on the selected rows and columns, but so far I haven't spotted a similar path for this situation. Any suggestions on directions for approaching this would be welcome.

Comment: These appear to be matrices of the form considered in [Ira Gessel, Gérard Viennot, *Binomial determinants, paths, and hook length formulae*, Advances in Mathematics, Volume 58, Issue 3, December 1985, Pages 300-321](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(85)90121-5). Thus, their submatrices are also matrices of this form. So you should perhaps be able to understand the rank of such a matrix as the maximum size of a matching in a bipartite graph, whose vertices correspond to points on the integer lattice and whose edges encode the existence of certain paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Looking through the paper it looks like they proved a bijection between the minors of a lower triangular binomial coefficient matrix and lattice paths, but the matrices I am considering are composed of blocks of such matrices and are not always square. Your idea of a understanding the rank of the matrix as a maximum matching is interesting, could you elaborate on how you see it?

Comment: I am afraid I'm not much in a position to elaborate on anything right now. Let me just say a couple more words. I still think all minors of your matrix are binomial determinants. Gessel and Viennot give a criterion (Corollary 2) for when such determinants are zero, in terms of inequalities between the things on top of the binomial coefficients and the things on the bottom.  So the rank of your matrix is essentially how many such inequalities you can get to hold simultaneously.